# Zooming to center using arduino in processing

Tags: copy, arduino, processing, zooming

I am currently making a camera using arduino and processing. It uses the webcam and has to ability to snap a photo when you snap your fingers, use a flash automatically when the room is below a certain light and zoom using an arduino knob. The current problem with the zoom is that it only zooms to the top left corner and I can't figure out how to make it zoom to the center of the image. Here is the code that does the zoom:

```
float s = 1.0;

s = map(arduino.analogRead(0), 1020, 0, 1, 10);
int scaleWidth = int(width/s);
int scaleHeight = int(height/s);

copy(cam, 0, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Thank you in advance to all those who reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
copy(cam, int((width - scaleWidth)*0.5), int((height - scaleHeight)*0.5), scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 0, 0, width, height);
```

update: made them into ints... Also, moved the multiplication to only be done once, which will make things a bit faster.

Comment: Copy calls for those two parameters to be floats, but scaleHeight and scaleWidth are ints. If there is a way to make them act as both, this might work. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: never mind, I just used /2 instead of *.5 (which is the same thing) and it worked. Thank you for the help!